# POST a file to a selected friend in my friend list using their ID

Tags: android

i am doing a sample Facebook application, in that i must **POST the file** to a particular friend **not to publish** in my friends list, not publish in my wall it must visible to the particular person only, i am using the following code it gives error and exception on default Facebook Utll class. I post my code here if it possible to correct else give a good solution...Thanks in Advance....

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params=getIntent().getExtras();
            String new_data= params.getString("new_frdId");
            params.putString("method", "publish_stream");
            params.putString("access_token", UI_Friend_Finder.accesstoken);

            params
            .putString(
                    "attachment",
                    "{\"name\":\""
                            + "\",\"href\":\"http://www.google.co.in"
                            + "\",\"description\":\"
                            + "\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\""
                            + ""
                            + "\",\"href\":\""
                            + "\"}]}");
    authenticatedFacebook.dialog(PostToFriend.this, "stream_publish",
            params, new TestUiServerListener());

                       finish();
                                }

                });
}
class TestUiServerListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            new AsyncFacebookRunner(authenticatedFacebook).request(postId,
                    new TestPostRequestListener());
        } else {
            PostToFriend.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void onCancel() {
    }

    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class TestPostRequestListener implements RequestListener {
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            String postId = json.getString("id");
            PostToFriend.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("Tests", "Testing wall post success");
                }
            });
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, final Object state) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            final Object state) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onIOException(IOException e, final Object state) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            final Object state) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class TestLoginListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        if (authenticatedFacebook.isSessionValid() == true) {
            String response = null;
            JSONObject jObject = null;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(
                        authenticatedFacebook.request("me"));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            editor.commit();

            finish();
        }
    }

    public void onCancel() {
    }

    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code..i put the stream.publish method inside the request function..it works well..

```
protected void postToWall(String temp2) {
   System.out.println("<<inside the post method>>");
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("message", _messageInput.getText().toString()"some text Here);
   params.putString("caption", "{*actor*} just posted a secret message.");
   params.putString("description","A secret message is waiting for you.  Click the link to    decode it.");
   params.putString("name", "A Secret Message For You");
 params.putString("picture","http://www.kxminteractive.com/Content/images/app_logos/secretMessage.png");
  params.putString("link", "http://www.kxminteractive.com/decrypt/");
  **mAsyncRunner.request(((temp2 == null) ? "me" : temp2) + "/feed",
                params, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener(),stream.publish);**
}
```